# Use a BLE keyring as smart button

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I have a [BLE keyring](https://www.gablys.com/en/gablys-premium/) that has a button (and apparently also various sensors). I want my C# application to react to button presses.

My issues:

- I don't know which Characteristic I should subscribe to.
- Even when subscribing to all characteristics notifications, the ValueChanged callback is never called.
- After a while I get an exception with message : "The device does not recognize the command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070016)".  **UPDATE**: this seems to be caused by unreliable connection. Circumvented with a simple try/catch.

Here's the result of BTHGattDump :

```
Microsoft Bluetooth GATT database viewer v1.00 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corp.
Selected device - GABLYS
Device Address - e7be9c955801  (STATIC)
[Service] Handle=0x0001 Type=0x1800(GAP)
    [Characteristic] Handle=0x0002 ValueHandle=0x0003 Type=0x2a00(Device Name) Properties=(Read/Write)
        [Value] GABLYS
    [Characteristic] Handle=0x0004 ValueHandle=0x0005 Type=0x2a01(Appearance) Properties=(Read)
        [Value] [0000]
    [Characteristic] Handle=0x0006 ValueHandle=0x0007 Type=0x2a04(Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters) Properties=(Read)
        [Value] [1000300000006400]
[Service] Handle=0x0008 Type=0x1801(GATT)
[Service] Handle=0x000c Type=0x180f(Battery)
    [Characteristic] Handle=0x000d ValueHandle=0x000e Type=0x2a19(Battery Level) Properties=(Read/Notify)
        [Value] [64]
        [Descriptor]  Handle=0x000f Type=0x2902(Client Configuration)
            [Value]  No subscription
[Service] Handle=0x0010 Type=0x1803(Link Loss)
    [Characteristic] Handle=0x0011 ValueHandle=0x0012 Type=0x2a06(Alert Level) Properties=(Read/Write)
        [Value] [00]
[Service] Handle=0x0013 Type=0x1802(Immediate Alert)
    [Characteristic] Handle=0x0014 ValueHandle=0x0015 Type=0x2a06(Alert Level) Properties=(WriteWithoutResponse)
[Service] Handle=0x0016 Type=4f172801-1867-a896-28c0-1bfbc156fa45
    [Characteristic] Handle=0x0017 ValueHandle=0x0018 Type=4f172491-1867-a896-28c0-1bfbc156fa45 Properties=(Read/Notify)
        [Value] [01]
        [Descriptor]  Handle=0x0019 Type=0x2902(Client Configuration)
            [Value]  No subscription
    [Characteristic] Handle=0x001a ValueHandle=0x001b Type=4f172492-1867-a896-28c0-1bfbc156fa45 Properties=(Read/Notify)
        [Value] [00]
        [Descriptor]  Handle=0x001c Type=0x2902(Client Configuration)
            [Value]  No subscription
[Service] Handle=0x001d Type=b0ad1523-99b2-7e1d-fc0d-6d399e1edf02
    [Characteristic] Handle=0x001e ValueHandle=0x001f Type=b0ad1524-99b2-7e1d-fc0d-6d399e1edf02 Properties=(Read/Notify)
        [Value] [00]
        [Descriptor]  Handle=0x0020 Type=0x2902(Client Configuration)
            [Value]  No subscription
    [Characteristic] Handle=0x0021 ValueHandle=0x0022 Type=b0ad1525-99b2-7e1d-fc0d-6d399e1edf02 Properties=(Read/Write)
        [Value] [00]
    [Characteristic] Handle=0x0023 ValueHandle=0x0024 Type=b0ad1526-99b2-7e1d-fc0d-6d399e1edf02 Properties=(Read/Write)
        [Value] [00]
[Service] Handle=0x0025 Type=89943300-2d54-b8cb-3af2-212144c5ca13
    [Characteristic] Handle=0x0026 ValueHandle=0x0027 Type=89943301-2d54-b8cb-3af2-212144c5ca13 Properties=(Read/Write)
        [Value] [00]
    [Characteristic] Handle=0x0028 ValueHandle=0x0029 Type=89943302-2d54-b8cb-3af2-212144c5ca13 Properties=(Read/Notify)
        [Value] [00]
        [Descriptor]  Handle=0x002a Type=0x2902(Client Configuration)
            [Value]  No subscription
    [Characteristic] Handle=0x002b ValueHandle=0x002c Type=89943304-2d54-b8cb-3af2-212144c5ca13 Properties=(Read/Write)
        [Value] [00]
```

My code (based on [HeartbeatFg from DrJukka](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=167)) :

```
public async void InitializeServiceAsync(string deviceId)
{
    try
    {
        Deinitialize();
        _service = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(deviceId);

        if (_service != null)
        {
            //we could be already connected, thus lets check that before we start monitoring for changes
            if (DeviceConnectionUpdated != null && (_service.Device.ConnectionStatus == BluetoothConnectionStatus.Connected))
            {
                DeviceConnectionUpdated(true, null);
            }

            _service.Device.ConnectionStatusChanged += OnConnectionStatusChanged;

            Subscribe(0x0016, 0x0017);

            //Let's try those once I can get at least the first one to work
            //Subscribe(0x0016, 0x001a);

            //Subscribe(0x001d, 0x001e);
            //Subscribe(0x0025, 0x0028);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: Accessing your device failed." + Environment.NewLine + e.Message);

        if (DeviceConnectionUpdated != null)
        {
            DeviceConnectionUpdated(false, "Accessing device failed: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}

public async void Subscribe(ushort serviceHandle, ushort characteristicHandle)
{
    try
    {
        var service = _service.Device.GattServices.Single(x => x.AttributeHandle == serviceHandle);
        var characteristic = service.GetAllCharacteristics().Single(x => x.AttributeHandle == characteristicHandle);

        if (characteristic.CharacteristicProperties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify))
        {
            var currentDescriptorValue = await characteristic.ReadClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync();

            if ((currentDescriptorValue.Status != GattCommunicationStatus.Success) || (currentDescriptorValue.ClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptor != GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify))
            {
                await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
            }

            characteristic.ValueChanged += Oncharacteristic_ValueChanged;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

private void Oncharacteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Oncharacteristic_ValueChanged from : {sender.AttributeHandle}");

    var data = new byte[args.CharacteristicValue.Length];
    DataReader.FromBuffer(args.CharacteristicValue).ReadBytes(data);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Oncharacteristic_ValueChanged : " + data[0]);
}

private void OnConnectionStatusChanged(BluetoothLEDevice sender, object args)
{
    if (sender.ConnectionStatus == BluetoothConnectionStatus.Connected)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Connected");
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Disconnected");
    }

    if (DeviceConnectionUpdated != null)
    {
        DeviceConnectionUpdated(sender.ConnectionStatus == BluetoothConnectionStatus.Connected, null);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
FindAllAsync devices.Count : 1
Found : GABLYS, id: \\?\BTHLEDevice#{7b122568-6677-7f8c-f8e9-af0eedb36e3a}_e7be9c955801#9&ce378e&1&0032#{6e3bb679-4372-40c8-9eaa-4509df260cd8}
'HeartbeatFg.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Dev\Perso\BLE\BLETestStuffWindows-master\HeartbeatFg\HeartbeatFg\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HeartbeatFg.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Dev\Perso\BLE\BLETestStuffWindows-master\HeartbeatFg\HeartbeatFg\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\System.Threading.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'HeartbeatFg.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Dev\Perso\BLE\BLETestStuffWindows-master\HeartbeatFg\HeartbeatFg\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HeartbeatFg.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Dev\Perso\BLE\BLETestStuffWindows-master\HeartbeatFg\HeartbeatFg\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\System.Linq.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'HeartbeatFg.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Dev\Perso\BLE\BLETestStuffWindows-master\HeartbeatFg\HeartbeatFg\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\System.Globalization.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'HeartbeatFg.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Dev\Perso\BLE\BLETestStuffWindows-master\HeartbeatFg\HeartbeatFg\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\System.IO.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Device GABLYS selected, now navigating to HeartBeatPage
OnNavigatedTo
'HeartbeatFg.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Dev\Perso\BLE\BLETestStuffWindows-master\HeartbeatFg\HeartbeatFg\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'HeartbeatFg.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Dev\Perso\BLE\BLETestStuffWindows-master\HeartbeatFg\HeartbeatFg\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\System.Reflection.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Connected
'HeartbeatFg.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Dev\Perso\BLE\BLETestStuffWindows-master\HeartbeatFg\HeartbeatFg\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
The thread 0x3d6c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x34a8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x368c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x12b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Disconnected
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Connected
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

Comment: What do services 4f172801-1867-a896-28c0-1bfbc156fa45, b0ad1523-99b2-7e1d-fc0d-6d399e1edf02 and 89943300-2d54-b8cb-3af2-212144c5ca13 do? A search on the internet does not yield anything for these services.

Comment: I actually have no clue about which of those "non standard" services does what. But one of them must be about the button so I'm expecting to be notified when pressing the button. But that doesn't happen :-(

Comment: Without this information it is nearly impossible to deduce what to do. If configuring every charactistic for notification did not help, it seems that things are more complicated and doing the right thing is a question of sheer luck. The only idea might be that the characteristic wants indications instead of notifications, but this is also just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know which Characteristic I should subscribe to.

So, you can retrieve all services and Characteristics the device supported and register ValueChanged event.

I test on TI SensorTag with the following code and it works for me. You can have a try. (I assume that your device supports button press service.)

```
    public async void InitializeServiceAsync(string deviceId)
    {
        try
        {
            _service = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(deviceId);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_service.Device.Name);
            if (_service == null)
                return;

            var service = _service.Device.GattServices;
            foreach (var item in service)
            {
                var chars = item.GetAllCharacteristics();
                foreach (var cha in chars)
                {
                    _service = item;
                    Subscribe(item.AttributeHandle, cha.AttributeHandle);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: Accessing your device failed." + Environment.NewLine + e.Message);
        }
    }

    public async void Subscribe(ushort serviceHandle, ushort characteristicHandle)
    {
        try
        {
            var service = _service.Device.GattServices.Single(x => x.AttributeHandle == serviceHandle);
            var characteristic = service.GetAllCharacteristics().Single(x => x.AttributeHandle == characteristicHandle);

            if (characteristic.CharacteristicProperties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("serviceHandle=" + serviceHandle);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("characteristicHandle=" + characteristicHandle);
                await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("register value changed event");
                characteristic.ValueChanged += Oncharacteristic_ValueChanged;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Call InitializeServiceAsync() method:

```
    var selector = GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(GattServiceUuids.GenericAccess);
    var devices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
    InitializeServiceAsync(devices[0].Id); //Use your device id intead of "devices[0].Id"
```

**UPDATE:**

Two edits I have made:

1. Traverse all all services and Characteristics.
2. Remove this statement：

`if ((currentDescriptorValue.Status != GattCommunicationStatus.Success) || (currentDescriptorValue.ClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptor != GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify))`

Comment: I omitted it here but my call to InitializeServiceAsync() is pretty much the same as yours. Otherwise, I fail to see where your code is doing something different from mine besides that I call ReadClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync and you don't ? I added a try/catch in the Subscribe method so that my issue n°3 is kinda circumvented (see updated post)

Comment: @Vinzz About the difference of the code please see my update. My code doesn't work for you? What kind of your BLE device? I can't open your link.